# Xamarin Insights with line numbers

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I've released an app using Xamarin and Xamarin Insights. Insights now successfully informs me when the app crashed but I only get a very vague stack trace **without line numbers** which makes it often impossible to track down the error.

Is there any way I can set up release builds so that crashes will contain stack traces including line numbers?

Thank you,
      David

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Why don't I have line numbers in my stack trace?](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/faq/#Why_dont_I_have_line_numbers_in_my_stack_trace)

> Why don't I have line numbers in my stack trace?
>
> In .NET you need to have the correct debug information (PDB files) alongside your dlls. Currently on iOS, it's not possible to package them, but we're working on a solution to upload them similar to how dSYMs are sent to us. On other platforms, you can bundle the .pdb files to get line numbers. There are also some known issues with getting line numbers when using async. We'll update the FAQ as we make progress on this.
>
> Although not as useful as a proper stack trace with line numbers, you can use the following snippet to collect some line number and file name information yourself by making a simple wrapper for Insights.Report. This uses built-in .NET Callerattributes to tell you where Report was called.

```
public static void Report (Exception exp, 
                        ReportSeverity severity= ReportSeverity.Error,          [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",              [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",            [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{  Insights.Report (exp, new Dictionary<string,object> {        {"Method",memberName},      
    {"File Name",sourceFilePath},      
    {"Line Number",sourceLineNumber},  
    }, severity);
}
```

Comment: I found that too but how does that work? Where and how do I upload/package those pdb files? The way I understand the little code snippet is that this would only work for caught exceptions but not if an uncaught exception is thrown - is that correct?

Comment: On Android you bundle them in your `.apk`

Comment: where are those pdb files? I looked in the entire output but can't find any. What are they called? Are there multiple?

Comment: hi @SushiHangover thanks for great information. I have 2 questions. are you talking about bundling pdb files and upload to google console? that doesnt increase app size? second quesiton, doest dSYM work for Android also? On my Xamarin Insights I see information only for IOS

Comment: @batmaci Increase apk size? Yes. (I do not recommend it). Insights is deprecated and HockeyApp replaced it, HockeyApp is also deprecated now and Azure Mobile Center replaced it ;-) You can download the Android crash report and use `mono-symbolicate` with the `.mSYM`, iOS use the crash report with `symbolicatecrash` and the `.dSYM`

Comment: @SushiHangover I am already using Mobile center and XI together because Mobile Center doesnt support handled exception reporting yet. By the way, in your sample LineNumber returns the number of caller inside catch, not the line number of the crash. Do you know why?

Comment: @batmaci I cut/pasted that from Xamarin's site and it is far from a "complete" implementation. I'm using `Crashlytics` for most projects now (Xamarin.iOS/Android) as I could not wait for  Microsoft (I have a tough time understanding why there is still not feature set parity after this amount of time) and `Crashlytics` dashboard is **light-years** ahead of Microsofts, but I will pull up my code when I have access to it as I wrote a full `StackTrace`  routine that I use to help Crashlytics create grouping for managed crashes.

Comment: @SushiHangover It looks interesting really. I really dont like hockeyapp interface. it is super hard to use as it slow and requires many clicks. Mobile center analytics are incomplete as well.